# Make constructor for JPanel to create circles?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i'm trying to create a project where i have a constructor that constructs circles with a x,y,width,height and then draws them using Jpanel.
Unfortunatley i have had no luck trying myself or finding any decent resources...

Can somebody help me out? Thanks..
I'm trying todo something like this

```
public Circle(int x , int y, int w, int h) {
    g.drawOval(x,y,w,h);
}
```

Also, i'm wondering if there are any better alternatives than Jpanel?
I'm looking to construct a application that can generate two circles and move, detect when they intersect and mark the intersected area.

Comment: What would `g` be in your case? Since you already seem to have found some code / knowledge, why don't you read it thoroughly? That `g.drawOval(x,y,w,h);` would belong into the component's (might be a panel) `paint( Graphics g)` method.

Comment: @Thomas I think you meant the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method instead of `paint` one...

Comment: @Frakcool you can override both but `paintComponent(...)` is probably the better one. :)

Comment: Yeah @Thomas I think I forgot to edit my comment yesterday, I was going to write that actually :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to draw using the Graphics class.

You would want something like this:

```
public class Circle {
public int x,y,w,h;
public Circle(int xx,yy,ww,hh) {
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    w = ww;
    h = hh;
}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public int getW() {
    return w;
}
public int getH() {
    return h;
}
}
class MainClass {
public circle = new Circle(50,50,50,50);
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval(circle.getX(),circle.getY(),circle.getW(),circle.getH());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is very simple once you get to learn it. Be sure to name the class constructor the same name as your class. Usually, you want to create private variables to assign the constructor's input to. In this case, we created private int x, y, w, and h, to assign the inputted int x, int y, int w, and int h in our constructor. When drawing, we take in a Graphics2D object to draw our desired shape, point, etc.

```
public class className{
    //Creating object properties
    private int x, y, w, h;  

    //Class Constructor
    public className(int x, int y, int w, int h){ 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

    //For drawing, you want to take in a Graphics2D Object (g2)
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
        g2.drawOval(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

In the main class or wherever your PaintComponent is, to use your constructor you type:

```
className objectName = new className(100, 200, 300, 400);
```

The code creates a new object with the name "objectName" from the constructor "className" with an x of 100, y of 200, w, 300, and h of 400. To call the draw function, simply type:

```
objectName.draw(g2); //Where g2 is some Graphics2D object
```